# Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile

Tags: linux, oracle

In my redhat 7.3 VM, I am trying to install oracle 11g r2 (11.2.0.1) for linux x86_64 but faced the following error during installation.

> Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile '/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See '/home/oracle/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2019-08-27_02-27-28PM.log' for details.

In the log, below is the last few lines:

```
INFO: Start output from spawned process:
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO:

INFO: /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/genclntsh

INFO: /bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++_nonshared
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

INFO: genclntsh: Failed to link libclntsh.so.11.1
make: *** [client_sharedlib] Error 1

INFO: End output from spawned process.
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: Exception thrown from action: make
Exception Name: MakefileException
Exception String: Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile '/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See '/home/oracle/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2019-08-27_02-27-28PM.log' for details.
Exception Severity: 1
```

For the installation prerequsite check, I have installed all the required packages with yum, except for the following packages which i couldn't install in RHEL7:

> libaio-0.3.105 (i386)
> compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3 (i386)
>
> libaio-devel-0.3.105 (i386)
>
> libgcc-3.4.6 (i386)
>
> libstdc++-3.4.6 (i386)
>
> unixODBC-2.2.11 (i386)
>
> unixODBC-devel-2.2.11 (i386)
>
> pdksh-5.2.14

Comment: "/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++_nonshared" and you couldn't install libstdc++-3.4.6 seem related, no...? Why couldn't you install those packages - they don't exist in your repository, or you can't reach any repositories, or you can only get later versions, or... something else?

Answer (score 1):

> Oracle Linux 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Support on Linux x86-64
>
> Starting with Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.4), Oracle Linux 7
>   and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 are supported on Linux x86-64.[Oracle®
>   Database Release Notes 11g Release 2 (11.2) for Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/relnotes.112/e23558/toc.htm#CJAFHBIA)

Answer (score 1):

```
"Exception String: Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile 
'/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. 
See '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2021-10-08_08-47-58PM.log' for details."
```

-> Above issue is sorted after applying rpm `"yum install glibc-devel-*"`